# postgresql complex query joing same table

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get those customers from a table 'transactions' which haven't created any transactions in the last 6 Months.

Table:

```
'transactions'
id, email, state, paid_at
```

To visualise:

```
|------------------------ time period with all transactions --------------------|
|-- period before month transactions > 0) ---|---- curr month transactions = 0 -|
```

I guess this is doable with a join showing only those that didn't have any transactions on the right side.

Example:
Month = November

#### The conditions for the left side should be:

1. COUNT(l.id) > 0
2. l.paid_at < '2013-05-01 00:00:00'

#### Conditions for the right side:

1. COUNT(r.id) = 0
2. r.paid_at BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'

Is join the right approach?

## Answer

```
SELECT
    C .email
FROM
    transactions C
WHERE
    (
        C .email NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                email
            FROM
                transactions
            WHERE
                paid_at >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
            AND paid_at <= '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
        )
        AND
        C .email IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                email
            FROM
                transactions
            WHERE
                paid_at <= '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
            
        )
    )
AND c.paid_at <= '2013-11-30 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. Use a subquery to get distinct customer ids for transactions in the last 6 months, and then select customers where their id isn't in the subquery.

```
select c.id, c.name
from customer c
where c.id not in (select distinct customer_id from transaction where dt between <start> and <end>);
```

Or, use a left join from customer to transaction, and filter the results to have transaction id null. A left join includes all rows from the left-hand table, even when there are no matching rows in the right-hand table. Explanation of left joins here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

```
select c.id, c.name
from customer c
    left join transaction t on c.id = t.customer_id
          and t.dt between <start> and <end>
where t.id is null;
```

The left join approach is likely to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.I posted my final query in the original psot

Comment: The left join is significantly faster on older versions of pgsql (pre 8.0 / 8.1) but on newer versions the subselects have pretty much caught up. Of course, until you test it, you can't really be sure.

Comment: @Wilberforce . . . I think the `distinct` is redundant in the first query.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't change the results, but I think it's easier to understand - you can cut and paste out the subquery and run it separately. It could also have an impact on execution time, although that could go either way, depending on the implementation.